# How run JavaScript form eclipse in command line

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp, eclipse-juno

Simple question:

I have one javaScript File , and eclipse.
Is it possible to run that script file using eclipse through command line.
If yes:
what i have to do .

If no:
Is there is any possibility to do this. any input will appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You'd need some sort of a JavaScript interpreter for that... And I don't really get how Eclipse is in the picture. This question in this form is not clear.

Comment: eclipse have JSDT right. Through which we can debug our script in eclipse. So i want to run it through jsdt of eclipse in command line.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse's JSDT has a built-in rhino interpreter (new in Eclipse Juno).  I have never used it myself, but it is possible to use it for interpreting your JS scripts.  [More information here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JSDT/Debug/Rhino).

Now if your JS script interacts with the DOM or the window, then rhino will not help you, but for pure, headless JS this will work.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using eclipse juno(e4) , command /handler support calling JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

[phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) is an webkit based headless web browser that could be invoked from command line. From [this](http://www.bryntum.com/blog/siesta-tip-integrating-phantomjs-with-your-ide/) tutorial you could learn how to integrate eclipse and phantomjs to execute javscript files.